# How to use javascript reduce method on an array which is a value for a property of an object and output a sum of only for positive elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have four objects (`account1`, `account2`, `account3`, `account4`) as following for which I want to get a 'sum of all deposits' and 'sum of all withdrawals'. Here deposits and withdrawals are shown in movements property. Here all positive values are deposits and negative values are withdrawals. But I only want to use reduce method without `flatMap` and `filter` method. I got all movements by doing following:

---

```
const transactions = accounts.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur.movements),
[]
);
```

This will reduce to `[200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300, 5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30, 200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460, 430, 1000, 700, 50, 90]`

But, how to set movements array so that I can get sum of positive values (which are deposits) and sum of negative values (which are withdrawals).

---

```
const account1 = {
  owner: 'Jonas Schmedtmann',
  movements: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],
  interestRate: 1.2, // %
  pin: 1111,
};

const account2 = {
  owner: 'Jessica Davis',
  movements: [5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30],
  interestRate: 1.5,
  pin: 2222,
};

const account3 = {
  owner: 'Steven Thomas Williams',
  movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460],
  interestRate: 0.7,
  pin: 3333,
};

const account4 = {
  owner: 'Sarah Smith',
  movements: [430, 1000, 700, 50, 90],
  interestRate: 1,
  pin: 4444,
};

const accounts = [account1, account2, account3, account4];
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this input?

Comment: `I have four objects (...) as following for which I want to get a 'sum of all deposits' and 'sum of all withdrawals'` - to me that sounds like you want a "sum of all deposits", etc for each account, separately.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this ?

```js
const
  account1 = { owner: 'Jonas Schmedtmann',movements: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],interestRate: 1.2, pin: 1111 }
, account2 = { owner: 'Jessica Davis',movements: [5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30],interestRate: 1.5, pin: 2222 }
, account3 = { owner: 'Steven Thomas Williams',movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460],interestRate: 0.7, pin: 3333 }
, account4 = { owner: 'Sarah Smith',movements: [430, 1000, 700, 50, 90],interestRate: 1,pin: 4444 }
  ;

const transactions = (...accounts) =>
  accounts.reduce((r,{movements})=>
  { 
  movements.forEach(v =>{ v > 0 ? r.deposits += v : r.withdrawals += v })
  return r
  }, {deposits:0,withdrawals:0})

console.log( transactions( account1, account2, account3, account4 ) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run two sum reduces with filters, or a combined reduce where you keep track of the positive/negative sums at once:

```js
const amounts = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300, 5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30, 200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460, 430, 1000, 700, 50, 90];
const pos = amounts.filter(am => am > 0).reduce((tot, v) => tot + v);
const neg = amounts.filter(am => am < 0).reduce((tot, v) => tot + v);
console.log('pos:', pos);
console.log('neg:', neg);

// or alternatively
const combo = amounts.reduce(([pos, neg], val) => val > 0 ? [pos + val, neg] : [pos, neg + val], [0, 0]);
console.log('combo:', combo);
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I want to know how to get idea that help me find logical solution like yours? One more question, can I reduce whole amounts array, which is movements in this case while checking conditions for pos and neg as above? I mean all statements in one reduce method.

Comment: @VishalShukla Practice. Seeing/writing a lot of code and solving a lot of problems. And yes, you could combine my `amounts.reduce` with your `accounts.reduce`. For the latter, your initial reduce value would (also) be `[0, 0]`, and in it you'd first run my reduce, then add it to the accumulator. Play around a bit, see if you can do it, otherwise create a new question with your attempt.

Comment: Also don't forget to mark this answer (or a better one) as the solution. _and perhaps upvote all answers that seem helpful, e.g. one person actually wrote the combined reduce, although I still suggest trying to write it first yourself as practice._

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to sum up `deposits` and `withdrawals`. Iterate each `account` using `array#reduce` and then iterate each `movements` using `array#forEach`, sum up `deposits` and `withdrawals` in the result accumulator.

```
const result = accounts.reduce((r, {movements}) => {
  movements.forEach(v => {
    v > 0 ? r.deposits += v : r.withdrawals += v;
  });
  return r;
 },{deposits: 0, withdrawals: 0});
```

```js
const account1 = {
  owner: 'Jonas Schmedtmann',
  movements: [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300],
  interestRate: 1.2, // %
  pin: 1111,
};

const account2 = {
  owner: 'Jessica Davis',
  movements: [5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30],
  interestRate: 1.5,
  pin: 2222,
};

const account3 = {
  owner: 'Steven Thomas Williams',
  movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460],
  interestRate: 0.7,
  pin: 3333,
};

const account4 = {
  owner: 'Sarah Smith',
  movements: [430, 1000, 700, 50, 90],
  interestRate: 1,
  pin: 4444,
};

const accounts = [account1, account2, account3, account4];
const result = accounts.reduce((r, {movements}) => {
  movements.forEach(v => {
    v > 0 ? r.deposits += v : r.withdrawals += v;
  });
  return r;
},{deposits: 0, withdrawals: 0});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Why does second parameter which is {movements} works exactly same as movements property in accounts object? Why is it taken in curly braces? How to decide that initial value for reducer should be object type or array type? and thank you for your answer. It is working.

Comment: Second parameter is the array item and we have destructured `movements` from object. Initial value of the reducer depends on use case, here we want to store the sum of `deposits` and `withdrawals`, object makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce` like this, to iterate through and accumulate the positive and negative movements.

```js
movements.reduce((acc, movement) => {
  if (movement > 0) acc[0] += movement
  else acc[1] += movement
    
  return acc
}, [0, 0])
```

This is that would look like as a function.

```js
let allTransactions = [200, 450, -400, 3000, -650, -130, 70, 1300, 5000, 3400, -150, -790, -3210, -1000, 8500, -30, 200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460, 430, 1000, 700, 50, 90]

function getPosNeg(movements) {
  return movements.reduce((acc, movement) => {
    if (movement > 0) acc[0] += movement
    else acc[1] += movement
    
    return acc
  }, [0, 0])
}

let [positive, negative] = getPosNeg(allTransactions)

console.log({positive: positive, negative: negative})
```